# fps drop in maximized windowed mode

Tags: gaming, microsoft-surface, fps

I have noticed when I play games in maximized windowed mode that my fps drops by close to 50%. I'm using a Surface Book with the dgpu from Nvidia. I have played with almost every setting I can think of, no luck. I am attempting to use an onscreen touch overlay to play the games (touch controller). Yet most games are unplayable in maximized windowed mode, and when not maximized the onscreen overlay doesn't fit correctly. Anyone familiar with this issue, or any fixes?

Thank you!

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107071) and [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107099) to get some information about the windowed mode and performance